# Poynting vector in metamaterials

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, poynting-vector, metamaterials

Poynting vector in a material with magnetic permeability $\mu$ is defined as

$\mathbf{S}=\frac{1}{\mu}(\mathbf{E} \times \mathbf{B})$

In certain media $\mu$ can be negative. In that case, $S$ will change sign. Does it mean that the wave propagation (in $\vec k=\vec E \times \vec  B$ direction) and energy transfer (in $\vec S$ direction) are happening in opposite directions? I think I'm mistaking something. Can anyone help?

Comment: Doesn’t a medium with negative $\mu$ have negative $\epsilon$ meaning their product is positive and so there’s no problem? If this is incorrect, what’s wrong with having a medium with negative $\mu$ which just reflects back the EM wave? Reflection is a thing.

Comment: @Dr jh Yes their product is positive. Could you explain how would that solve the problem? S contains only $\mu$

Comment: No, I think you are correct. I remember seeing it. Check abstract https://www.osapublishing.org/ol/abstract.cfm?uri=ol-31-14-2169. I think it has been discussed widely in the literature in those days. BTW Don't define Poynting vector with equation. Poynting vector is flow of energy. Specific equation is a consequence of medium's response

Comment: @Cryo I think they both should be in the same direction. But I don't know how would negative values modify the expressions to reconcile with that

Comment: I’m saying if they are both negative, the wave will reflect. So the Poynting vector necessarily changes sign.